# Does Common Seeding Data Exist Somewhere for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

**Original Question**

To lessen the amount of typing in `db/seeds.rb`, I'm wondering if there exists popular seed data/code somewhere that I could just copy and paste from and make minor edits to as necessary.

Specifically, here are some resources I would like to find seed data/code for:

*cites*: all cities within a specific state

*states*: all US states (and hopefully their abbreviations)

*disabilities*: all disabilities within the DSM-5

*zip-codes*: all zip codes for a specific state

Example:  Below I had to type out myself in order to seed the **Ethnicities** table.  What would have been ideal is if somewhere else somebody had already typed it up and all I had to do was copy and paste it:

```
ethnicity_list = [
  "American Indian/Alaska Native",
  "Asian/Pacific Islander",
  "Black/African American",
  "Caucasian",
  "Hispanic/Mexican American",
  "Multiracial",
  "Other"
]

ethnicity_list.each do |name|
  Ethnicity.create(name: name)
end
```

**Answer**

Here is the current best process I am using for seeding:

1. Find the raw data (usually you can find it on the internet).  Copy and paste it into a text file.  You will probably need to format it a bit for parsing. Example for States data: `public/states.txt`:

   ```
   Florida|FL
   Georgia|GA
   Hawaii|HI
   Idaho|ID
   ...
   ```
2. Open the file, parse the data, and then seed it: `db/seeds.rb`:

   ```
   File.open('public/states.txt', 'r') do |file|
     file.read.each_line do |state|
       name, name_abbrev = state.chomp.split("|")
       State.create(name: name, name_abbrev: name_abbrev)
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

Find the raw data (usually you can find it on the internet). Copy and paste it into a text file. You will probably need to format it a bit for parsing. Example for States data: public/states.txt:

```
Florida|FL
Georgia|GA
Hawaii|HI
Idaho|ID
...
```

Open the file, parse the data, and then seed it: db/seeds.rb:

```
File.open('public/states.txt', 'r') do |file|
  file.read.each_line do |state|
    name, name_abbrev = state.chomp.split("|")
    State.create(name: name, name_abbrev: name_abbrev)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For countries you have the [countries gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries)

For cities you have the [cities gem](https://github.com/joecorcoran/cities)

For the zip codes it could be more problematic, but you can also add them as seeds as the same for disabilities.

For seeding please take a look at [SeedMigration](https://github.com/harrystech/seed_migration) as explained in [this blog post](http://engineering.harrys.com/2014/06/09/seed-migrations.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me best choice [ffaker](https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/ffaker) for fake data + [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to generate records